# Count the number of different value of a field, and get the average per minute

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have some domain like this:

```
domain |
A      |
B      |
C      |
D      |
...
```

One domain can be called in one request, now I want to know what is the average request number per minute for a domain (no matter what domain is). So I split it into three steps:

1. get the total request number per minute
2. get the number of domains been called per minute
3. avg = total request number per minute / number of domain per minute

I have got the result of the first step by:

```
index="whatever" source="sourceurl"
| bin _time span=1m
| stats count as requestsPerMin by _time
```

However, I don't know how to get the number of domains that been called. For example, in a minute, domain A has been called twice, domain B has been called once, so the number of domains that been called should be two. But I don't know which query can get this result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want a [`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart) instead:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp domain=* source="sourceurl"
| timechart span=1m dc(domain) as count by source
```